# Including Shared C Library (.SO) in a .NET Core Docker Image

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, raspberry-pi, dockerfile

I am trying to use a C# library in my .net Core 5.0 project, which is a C# wrapper for a [C Assembly for ws281x](https://github.com/rpi-ws281x/rpi-ws281x-csharp) LEDs. The library requires the that the [Shared C library (ws2811.so)](https://github.com/rpi-ws281x/rpi-ws281x-csharp#installation) be built before running the framework. I have successfully built and installed the C shared library into /usr/lib for my raspberry pi, and have tested it to confirm it works.

The issue lies in that within my Dockerfile, I don't know how/where to properly install this shared C library. My current dockerfile is as follows:

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source
COPY ./ /source

# installs NodeJS and NPM
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential

RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm --version

# installing c wrapper for ws2811 -- Here is where I need HELP
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python
RUN apt-get install -y python-setuptools python-dev build-essential python-pip

RUN pip install scons && git clone https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x.git \
         && cd rpi_ws281x && scons && gcc -shared -o ws2811.so *.o

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY control/ *.csproj ./control/
RUN dotnet restore -r linux-arm

# copy everything else and build app
COPY control/. ./control/
WORKDIR /source/control
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app -r linux-arm --self-contained false --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim-arm32v7
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./control"]
```

As it is now, the dockerfile builds correctly and the app launches. However, when I try to use a method to invoke the ws2811.so library through P/Invoke, I get the following error:

> **System.DllNotFoundException:** Unable to load shared library 'ws2811.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libws2811.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Which is telling me that P/Invoke is unsuccessful in finding the ws2811.so library. Where should I put this ws2811.so library so that my C# code can access it? I've tried placing it with the source code, I've played around with installing it in docker, but am really at a standstill and don't know where to go from here.

For a bit more information, the C# code to invoke this C-shared library is as follows. It is essentially the same thing as done in the example on the ws281x GitHub (as linked earlier).

```cs
public void setRgb()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("R: " + r + "\tG: " + g + "\tB: " + b);

            var settings = Settings.CreateDefaultSettings(false);
            var controller = settings.AddController(88, Pin.Gpio18, StripType.WS2812_STRIP, 255, false);

            Color color = new Color();
            color = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);

            using (var rpi = new WS281x(settings)) // EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE (System.DllNotFound)
            {
                rpi.SetLedCount(88);
                rpi.SetAll(color);
            }
        }
```

Any help, guidance, or resources are extremely appreciated! Thanks so much :)

Comment: First comment: is the shared library even present in your final container image? (you are using multi-stage builds, where each container may or may not include bits from a previous container). Secondly,for possible locations, you can put it in the same location as the application dlls; `DllImport` can/should pick up shared libraries from the current working directory.

Comment: I'm quite a nooby at Docker and that's actually what I'm trying to do, place the shared library into the final container image. I build it using scons and GCC, but I'm not sure how to then include it in the image. How would I go about that? Also -- I will try placing it in the current working directory and get back to you. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're only copying the published application to the final docker image `COPY --from=build /app ./` and that source directory doesn't have your SO since dotnet publish isn't gonna put it there. You need to get the final bits copied into that last stage

Comment: That makes sense to me, I just don't know how to actually copy the ws2811.so into the final docker image. When I try to copy ws2811.so into ./, I get an error telling me ws2811.so is nowhere to be found. How can I grab the .so file from my build folder (/rpi_ws281x) and put it into the final staging area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker has the concept of a "build context".  That defines the directory from which files are accessed.  So when you say `COPY foo /foo` in your Dockerfile, that's copying the `foo` file from the build context and places it in the root folder of your container with the name `foo`.  You set the build context when running the `docker build` command. Very often, people use `.` as the build context which means the current working directory that you're running the command from (e.g. `docker build -t app .`).  So it depends on what directory your build context is. That's where you should be placing the .SO library so that you can then add a `COPY` instruction in your Dockerfile to copy it into your container image.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much for the clear explanation and solution. Put the ws2811.so into my working directory and added `COPY ws2811.so ./` to my Dockerfile, works like a charm :-)